# How to install CS:GO to a USB?

Tags: usb, games, steam

I just got Ubuntu on my Chromebook and I am trying to run CSGO on Steam on the laptop. I purchased a 32 gb usb drive so I can install CSGO on it from Steam, but I am not sure how to route Steam to install to the USB instead of to the hard drive which is out of storage.

Answer (score 3):

In Steam settings you can choose a game download location.

Also when you download a game, you are asked where you want to install it.